# Facebook/Twitter/Google+ custom Dialog and buttons with counters?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, twitter, google-plus

**Full Site Live View:** https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/Replaced-With-Divs.html#
**JSFiddle Snippet View:** http://jsfiddle.net/JWXrk/

I would like to set up a custom share feature on my page. Once someone has shared the page, it will add to the counter in the white space of each image.

[image]

The above is a random image from Google to show an example. I would like to be able to customize the share description and the image, however I am not sure if I am able to set this up without a Facebook API key?

They are simply links with styles at this moment in time;

```
<div class="ImgWrap">
    <a class="MedBtn" href="#" id="Facebook-Australia" original-title="Click to share on Facebook"></a>
    <a class="MedBtn" href="#" id="Twitter-Australia" original-title="Click to share on Twitter"></a>
    <a class="MedBtn" href="#" id="GooglePluss-Australia" original-title="Click to share on Google+"></a>
</div>
```

The reason why I have only spoken mainly about Facebook is due to being more familiar with Facebook, although I would like to do the similar with the Tweet and Google+.

Thank you for any time spent in following up my question and for any help and/or advice.

Best Regards,

Tim

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of jquery plugins that already do the same function as you require...

http://sharrre.com/ for example, which looks like this:

http://sharrre.com/example1.html

You can modify the CSS to get the end result you want.  Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: I downloaded the files, uploaded them, edited nothing and this is the result: https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/share/index.html - This is very buggy as explained on their website.

Comment: Because you are on a secure server you must call jQuery from a secure location...

Replace the jQuery at the top of your code with :

    `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: I did not even notice this link to JQuery on Google, regardless, nothing has changed upon updating as you can now view on the live version. Best Regards, Tim

Answer (score 1):

Here is the little example:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: '<TITLE>',
    link: '<YOUR_LINK>',
    picture: '<IMG_URL>',
    caption: '<CAPTION>',
    description: '<DESCRIPTION>',
    message: '<MESSAGES>'
    },
    function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            $.ajax({ 
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<FILE.PHP>'
                data: {
                    // PAGE_DATA - The page id, or something which links the actual page and his share's count
                    postData: <PAGE_DATA>
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.error)
                        return false;
                    // As I said, you must adapt your HTML / CSS
                    var actualCount = $('.MedBtn.count[data-type="fb-share"]');
                    actualCount.text(parseInt(actualCount.text() + 1));
                };
            });
        }
    }
);
```

You can see the result (sample) right here: http://jsfiddle.net/AeqQj/

Comment: I do not understand your provided code/JSFiddle. I understand the top section allowing me to add the details to what is to be shared (can I have a dozen of these for one page?), however I am not sure what the rest is, I presume it is to submit to a database once it is confirmed that they have shared but on your example there is no link, it is just a number? Best Regards, Tim

Comment: The provided JSFiddle shows you the final result :) Adding +1 to the actual count. So, according to the example, when the user successfully shared your page, a php file is called through an ajax request. (Yup, you must write this one, with a DB connection in it, and a error handler). If no error occurred, the actual count is incremented. In any case, if you are not comfortable with PHP / SQL, it would be easier to keep the original buttons ;)

Comment: Yes, I am not comfortable with PHP/SQL, however now is a good time than any other! How do I call the above code in a link for example, I need to have a couple of dozen on one page so can this also be in an external file? Lastly, I do not understand how to setup a database, columns and rows. Can column 1 row 1 be called 'Facebook' and branch off where Column 2 row 1 has more lines in?

Comment: Wow, they really need to make a markup for creating a table, it took me ages but I have finally added a question regarding the database here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734252/how-to-setup-a-database-table-on-1and1-server

Answer (score 0):

You must adapt your HTML / CSS to allow the counting to show in the white box, anyway, you can increment it after the callback.

```
if (response && response.post_id) {
  // Add +1 to the actual count / update the count in DB.
}
```

Comment: I'm not actually sure how to set up the initial share on Facebook/Twitter/Google+. Also, this counter, where does the information get recorded? Do I need to set up a database?

Comment: Yes, you need to set up a DB to record informations about the count, I'll write you a little code to show you how to do it if it's necessary.

Comment: Oh dear! This is my weakest subject so to speak! Setting up databases are a nightmare for me, however I was needing to set one up somehow for the other buttons anyway... Thank you for your help :)